# ps-print-region-with-faces errors with "wrong number of arguments message"

Tags: emacs, elisp

Trying to ps-print-region-with-faces after setting customized configuration.
So I have the following functions defined:

```
(defun print-two-pages-region ()
  (interactive)
  (if (y-or-n-p "Sure you want to print region (2/page)?")
      (ps-two-per-page-region)
    (message "Did not print region.")
    ))

(defun ps-two-per-page-region ()
  (interactive)
  (require 'ps-print)
  (ps-save-default)
  (ps-set-2perpage)
  (ps-print-region-with-faces)
  (ps-restore-default)
  )
```

This is the error message:

```
Ä$" [from to filename ps-print-with-faces t] 5 ("/pkg/gnu/share/emacs/24.3/lisp/ps-print.elc" . 64113) (ps-print-preprint-region current-prefix-arg)], 0
```

I believe I should pass some arguments to ps-print-region-with-faces function. Not sure what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend two useful steps:

- byte-compile your file with `M-x byte-compile-file RET RET`.  The byte-compiler will give you warnings when you call a function that's either unknown or with the wrong number of arguments.
- `C-h f ps-print-region-with-faces RET` will give you documentation about that function.  The third line will show you the "signature", which indicates what arguments are expect.

Comment: Thanks Stefan. Compiling emacs is not an option, I use a network centralized version that I can't play with or modify.
I checked the documentation and found the following: (ps-print-region-with-faces FROM TO &optional FILENAME) ... I still don't see what I need to provide. The Files menu "postscript region" is bound to the same function and it works fine. Also, if I do M-x ps-print-region-with-faces it also works fine and prints the region without the need for any arguments.

Comment: I didn't tell you to compile Emacs.  I only told you to byte-compile your Elisp file.  As for the missing arguments, you need to provide FROM and TO which are the two buffer positions that delimit the region you want to print.  You probably want to use `(region-beginning)` for one and `(region-end)` for the other.  When called via `M-x` (or a menu, or ...) these arguments are provided by Emacs according to the `interactive` specification in the definition of the function.

Answer (score 1):

According to Stefan's answer, this should work:

```
(defun ps-two-per-page-region (start end)
  (interactive "r")
  (require 'ps-print)
  (ps-save-default)
  (ps-set-2perpage)
  (ps-print-region-with-faces start end)
  (ps-restore-default))
```